# Cross-browser change an A tags' HREF

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

it seems I can not find `document.getElementById().href` in the Javascript reference, there are a lot of sites saying to use this to change the href of a link. Is this safe? Will it work in all browsers? Or should I just already have my other link ready and replace the old one when it is no longer needed?

I only have 2 possible values I will for the link, depending on the last action performed by the user, either "delete" or "revive". So I guess replacing the link rather than changing it would not be much of a burden. I would rather change it if it will work in all browsers though.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't find it in any reference, as it's not a single construct, it's the combination of two.

Use the [document.getElementById method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a specific element, and if that element is an anchor tag, you can use the [href property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533867%28VS.85%29.aspx) to set the URL.

Both are specified in the [DOM level 1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/), so they are safe to use in any browser that isn't more than a decade old, and most that are a bit older too.

Comment: There is no reason to provide a link to DOM 1, when there are DOM 2 standards: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML

Answer (score 1):

Guffa is correct. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure it is "safe" nothing bad will happen. It works in all browser I have tested it in, and is the standard in which JavaScript changes the values of elements attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked a similar question here: [Retrieving HTML attribute values "the DOM 0 way"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456231/retrieving-html-attribute-values-the-dom-0-way)

Check out the answers. The conclusion is that the attributes `src`, `href` and `style` are not safe and a JavaScript library is recommended.

For the `href` attribute, I recommend jQuerys `attr()` method.

```
// retrieve the anchor by ID
var anchor = $('#anchorID');

// get the href attribute
var href = anchor.attr('href');

// set the href attribute
anchor.attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
```