# dynamic link making and pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a link like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">test</a>
```

and a javascript variable:

```
var t='this';
```

How can I make the click on the link go to `http://www.example.com/'+this` using pure javascript?

(so clicking makes a dynamic url that has the variable t at the end)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser change an A tags' HREF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632091/cross-browser-change-an-a-tags-href)

Comment: I removed the jQuery tag because it seemed you want a solution not involving any library. Just roll it back if you want to use jQuery, although you will also find that such a question exists for jQuery as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide your anchor an id:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" id="mylink">test</a>
```

and then:

```
var t = 'this';
document.getElementById('mylink').onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = this.href + t;
    return false;
};
```

obviously if you are putting this script in the `<head>` section you might need to wait for the DOM to be ready before attempting to attach click handlers:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('mylink').onclick = function() {
        window.location.href = this.href + t;
        return false;
    };
};
```

If you cannot modify your DOM to provide an unique id to your anchor you could use the [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) method which will return you an array of all elements with the given tag in your DOM and then you will have to loop through them and attach the `onclick` handler to your anchor. In order to identify it between all the links that you might have, you will have to use either its innerHTML text or the current href property.

Comment: Hei Darin, this is okay but every time I click the link it adds t to the link each time...so if I click twice it goes to http://www.example.com/thisthis...is this normal?

Comment: @David19801, normally when you click on the link, you are redirected to a different page, so how are you able to click twice on this link?

Comment: click, go back, click again...but really I want it to work with middle mouse to open the link in new window...any idea?

Comment: @David19801, I have updated my code with another approach that consists in canceling the default action and using window.location.href to perform the redirect. This way you are not modifying the href property of the actual DOM element.

Comment: This is better than this.href=this.href+t, but is there any way to make it work with middle mouse button so it loads in a new page AND does not rewrite the href permanently?  I have been reading the syntax of javascript and I think it is impossible so far...OK I DONE IT USING open()!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Darin solition, this opens into a new window and does not modify original;

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('mylink').onclick = function() {
        window.open(this.href + t);
        return false;
    };
};
```