# How can I add "href" attribute to a link dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add the `href` attribute to a link dynamically using JavaScript?

I basically want to add a `href` attribute to `<a></a>` dynamically (i.e. when the user clicks on specific image in the website).

So from:

```
<a>Link</a>
```

I need to go to:

```
<a href="somelink url">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 250, accepted):

```
var a = document.getElementById('yourlinkId'); //or grab it by tagname etc
a.href = "somelink url"
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could directly access the attributes as fields (compare to my solution below, using `setAttribute`). Does anybody know if this approach is standard?

Comment: I think on the a DOM element href is an attribute you can set directly by el.href. Instead, setAttribute(el,attr) is used to add some custom attributes to a particular DOM element, so in this case there's no need to use it to set a std. attr

Comment: But are both ways *correct*? Not trying to criticise the answer -- it may well be correct. But on the web, it isn't sufficient to get something that works for you. It needs to work in all browsers, and that means you need to follow standards. FWIW, this works for me too (in Firefox), but I'm interested to know whether it is actually a standard way to do it. The W3C DOM specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html) doesn't seem to mention it.

Comment: These are the interfaces to interact with elements more easily. For examples, all links has the methods defined in [`HTMLLinkElement`](http://krook.org/jsdom/HTMLLinkElement.html) which supports setting certain fields such as `href`. You have to look in the reference to see which one you can use without having to `setAttribute`. Another example is the `<table>` element ([HTMLTableElement](http://krook.org/jsdom/HTMLTableElement.html)) where you can use `insertRow()` to insert new rows without having to create the `<tr>` and append it to the table.

Comment: And yes, setting `.href` is the standard way of setting it. `setAttribute()` is also supported.

Comment: @Thai OK great that answers my question. I was citing the DOM Core, but it turns out you have to look in the DOM HTML extensions (http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-35143001). So each element has a certain set of properties which can be used; `setAttribute` is more general.

Comment: @mgiuca exactly! setAttribute could be thought of a custom attribute manager :)

Comment: @mgiuca: In general for HTML DOMs, you should prefer using properties rather than `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()`, which are broken in IE and don't always do what you might expect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456231/retrieving-html-attribute-values-the-dom-0-way/4456805#4456805

Answer (score 39):

I assume you know how to get the DOM object for the `<a>` element (use `document.getElementById` or some other method).

To add any attribute, just use the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) method on the DOM object:

```
a = document.getElementById(...);
a.setAttribute("href", "somelink url");
```

Comment: pal, setattribute is pretty non-standard for modifying attributes. To access or modify the current values, you should use the properties. For example, use elt.value instead of elt.setAttribute('value', val).  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute#Notes

Comment: @naveen It says "most notably in XUL", which is presumably not what this is. I'm not sure which other values it refers to ("certain attributes" is very vague), but `setAttribute` is clearly the standard (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082), and W3C doesn't define any attributes it doesn't work for.

Conversely, I can guarantee that using the property will fail for certain attribute names. Such as `tagName`, and `setAttribute` -- those are already fields/methods of the Element interface. I don't see anywhere in the W3C document which mentions properties for attributes.

Comment: @mgiuca: It seems you found the relevant spec after posting that last comment. I don't understand your point about properties failing, and then mentioning `tagName`. Are you talking about custom attributes?

Comment: I mean that DOM (even as implemented in the browser) is a generic spec for working with XML trees in general, not just HTML. When working with arbitrary XML elements, the only way to reliably get and set attributes is `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`; `"tagName"` is an example of an attribute that can't work as a property. Only when working with HTML, and for certain attributes defined in the DOM HTML spec, can you use the properties to read and assign attributes.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding, but that's still confusing. `tagName` **is** a property of `Element` objects in JavaScript, in both HTML and XML DOMs, and you cannot get an element's tag name via `getAttribute("tagName")` (except in IE, whose implementation of `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` is broken), which seems precisely the opposite of what you're saying.

Comment: Yeah it was a confusing example, but what I'm talking about only works for confusing examples. I'm not talking about the `tagName` property (that is, the member of Element objects which tells you the tag name of the element). I'm talking about a hypothetical XML element with an attribute called `tagName`. For example, `<myelement tagName="foo">`. You could not get the "foo" out of that element using `elem.tagName`, because that name is reserved. You would have to use `elem.getAttribute("tagName")` which is the generic way to read XML attributes.

Comment: Aaahhh, now I understand. Yes, you're right. With XML you haven't really got an option anyway: attribute-related properties simply don't exist. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 8):

```
document.getElementById('link-id').href = "new-href";
```

---

I know this is an old post, but here's a one-liner that might be more suitable for some folks.

Answer (score 8):

More actual solution:

```
<a id="someId">Link</a>

const a = document.querySelector('#someId');
a.href = 'url';
```

Comment: Finally, someone who uses `querySelector`

Answer (score 7):

First, try changing `<a>Link</a>` to `<span id=test><a>Link</a></span>`.

Then, add something like this in the javascript function that you're calling:

```
var abc = 'somelink';
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<a href="' + abc + '">Link</a>';
```

This way the link will look like this:

```
<a href="somelink">Link</a>
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stackoverflow. The OP's question seems to be about how to add an `href` to an **existing** `a` tag  (*I basically want to add a href attribute to <a></a> dynamically*). However, this answer seems to be explaining how to **create** an `a` tag with an `href`.

Comment: @MoisheLipsker It still works. Even if it does destroy the original, it does still in a way "set" the href. However, it is not practical as it does not retain the previous link without destroying it, thus potentially destroying other attributes and information.

Comment: This is  a slightly cumbersome approach. For one it's polluting the DOM with an additional element unnecessarily just to select an element inside it rather than just adding that ID to the a tag and selecting it directly. It's also destroying and recreating the a tag using a string replace which is risky (the value of abc could break your html) and unnecessarily mutates the DOM when you can use `element.setAttribute('href', abc)`

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I wanted to dynamically set the link href after it's been clicked

```
<a id='dynamic'>link text</a>

document.getElementById("dynamic").addEventListener("click", onClick_dynamic)

function onClick_dynamic(e){
    const nextPage = getNextPage()
    document.getElementById("dynamic").href = _BASE_URL + "?nextPage=" + nextPage
    // e.default processing sends user to href
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there seems plenty good answers here, but none of them seemed simple enough for what I was "told" to do in the 2022 Udemy Web Development Bootcamp by Angela.

So I remembered how simple the use of scriplets was and figured to try it and it works just as well.

For those like me who are learning let me explain:
. - takes you to current URL
then static path
then dynamic variable generated for each post (its a blog website)

```
<a href="./posts/<%= post.title %>">Read More</a>
```

This is using JS inside an EJS page

same solution is also given in the solution lecture of the bootcamp here:
https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-web-development-bootcamp/learn/lecture/12385596#overview

Lecture 317

Answer (score -2):

Single line solution

```
<a id="yourId">Link</a>
document.querySelector("#yourId").href("URL")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Answer (score -4):

javasicript added

```
var x = "www.google.com";
vay y = "550";
var z= x+y;
document.write('<a href="' + z + '">GONDER</a>');
```

Comment: They want to change an existing link instead of creating a new one. Plus, `document.write` is a horrible method that rarely should even be thought about for use.

Comment: this is the best method

Comment: Not even close. It is very dangerous, as XSS is very easy in your method. In addition, document.write clears the entire webpage. Another problem you have with your answer is that the OP (original poster) here does not want a *new* link, but rather an *existing* link, and they want it to have the href of it edited.