# Change of url under header with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically change url under the header with js function. Unfortunately I stack on some easy part.

According to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689344/how-can-i-add-href-attribute-to-a-link-dynamically-using-javascript) I tried to solve that problem...

Simplified version of my code:

```
<div class="details">
  <h1 id="title">Old title</h1>
  <h3 id="author">
    <a id="aId" href="https://www.google.pl/">Old author</a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var title = $("#title");// the id of the heading
var author = $("#author");// id of author 

title.text("New title");
author.text("New author");
var a = document.getElementById('aId');
a.href = "bing.com"
```

The problem is that Author now is not clickable. Could you help me?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your help!
Solution:

```
var title = $("#title");// the id of the heading
var author = $("#author a");// id of author 

title.text("New title");
author.text("New author");
author.attr("href", "http://bing.com")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `author.text("New author");`, you are removing the link form within the `<h3 id="author">` element. It basically goes from:

```
<h3 id="author">
  <a id="aId" href="https://www.google.pl/">Old author</a>
</h3>
```

to

```
<h3 id="author">New author</h3>
```

You should be changing the name of the author within the link instead of the `h3` directly, as follows:

```
 var title = $("#title");// the id of the heading
 var author = $("#author a");// id of author 

 title.text("New title");
 author.text("New author");
 var a = document.getElementById('aId');
 a.href = "http://bing.com"
```

Pay special attention that the selector of the author has changed to be the `a` element within the `#author` element.

You can test the code here: (wait 3 seconds and you will see the link being updated)

https://jsfiddle.net/nq8hwr2x/

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It is working, but do I really need to two identifiers? like '#author a' and 'aId'? Is there more elegant way?

Comment: There's a more elegant way, I just tried to keep changes to a minimum. You can do `author.text("New author").attr("href", "http://bing.com");` and do all the changes in one line.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are nesting the `<a>` tag inside a `<h3>` tag, which is causing the link to be removed when changing the `text` attribute. You can just lose the `<h3>` tag and set the `<a>` text directly:

```js
$("#title").text("New title");
$("#aId").text("New author").attr("href", "http://bing.com/");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details">
  <h1 id="title">Old title</h1>
  <a id="aId" href="https://www.google.pl/">Old author</a>
</div>
```