# Passing UTM params to another page through a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

How to get parameters section in a URL after ? and put it in a button who's href + params leads to another landing page . Means I need to pass UTM params to another page.So, I am thinking to apply JS in the button who will add those UTM params to it's original href.

home page: https://www.fylehq.com/?utm_campaign=Capterra%20-%20November%202018&utm_source=capterra

this is the page after clicking button:
https://www.fylehq.com/start?hsCtaTracking=f52ee3b4-0d97-42fe-bbee-c5a082ae2985%7Cc39c4eda-024b-40bd-8330-a06ac2ab146f

and this is what I need:
https://www.fylehq.com/start?utm_campaign=Capterra%20-%20November%202018&utm_source=capterra

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this post: [How can I add "href" attribute to a link dynamically using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689344/how-can-i-add-href-attribute-to-a-link-dynamically-using-javascript)

Read the post, create the href you want and replace it like in the post, or you can get the url and simply add the UTM parameters to it like this

```
a.href = a.href + "add here"
```

Comment: I guess it's not, the link above is only to store the link in <a> upon clicking will take to the link you set in a.href. My question is different, it says how to cut a URL and paste the required part in another url via button

Comment: maybe you right but its still the same idea, get the href of the url, change the url, and paste the href back, where are your code examples of things you tried?