# How to tag an affiliate link nofollow and open in new tab?

Tags: html

I have integrated in my site affiliate links from awin.com and amazon.com, but they are not tagged with nofollow and don't open in a new tab. This is something I want to change. I know this form of code:

```
<a href="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" >Link Text</a>
```

I have used the Amazon-Banners, which have an iframe. What should I do here?

But how I should do that, when I'm not allowed to change the links?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: "when I'm not allowed to change the links" why? I mean, are you using some CMS? Which one?

Comment: Amazon and Awin say that you are not allowed to change the links. I have a Blogspot Blog. But it's not forbidden to set them to nofollow and new tab.

Comment: You can add attributes by JS like here:
[How can I add “href” attribute to a link dynamically using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689344/how-can-i-add-href-attribute-to-a-link-dynamically-using-javascript)

Comment: Oh my God, I don't really know how to do that. I have tried to supplement the tags with nofollow and target blank in the banner links but it didn't work. The links still open in the tab of my blog.

Comment: The Links are bedded in the following code: <b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "Familie")'>
<!-- link 1 -->
</b:if>