# jquery html($("<img>").attr("src", this.href)); not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I'm  using a simple jquery function for an image gallery. There is a div of thumbnails, then the target div where the large images are loaded into after one clicks on a thumbnail.

It's working fine in all browsers, with the exception of Safari, where the image's absolute url is loaded, opposed to being loaded inside of the div.

Here's the jquery code:

```
$("#thumbnails a").click(function() {
    $("#work").html($("<img>").attr("src", this.href));

    return false;
});
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**`this.href` is not safe!**

Use `$(this).attr('href')` and it will work.

Check out my question here: [Retrieving HTML attribute values "the DOM 0 way"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456231/retrieving-html-attribute-values-the-dom-0-way)

It explains that there are several HTML attributes (`href` among them) that are problematical, so one should use jQuery's `attr()` to retrieve their values.

Quote from an answer on that page:

> For example, the href property of an
>    element always reports a fully
>   qualified URL while
>   getAttribute("href") will return the
>   string specified in the HTML href
>   attribute verbatim. Except, of course,
>   in IE. jQuery's attr() does attempt to
>   normalize this kind of inconsistency.

---

**UPDATE**

I figured it out. You didn't ensure that the jQuery code runs after the DOM is ready. Always place all your jQuery code inside the ready handler:

```
$(function() {

    // place all jQuery code here

});
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Try this code:

```
$('#thumbnails a').click(function() {
    $('#work').empty().html( '<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' );
    return false;       
});
```

I should have seen this earlier. The argument of the html() function has to be a string.

---

**UPDATE 3**

It could be that Safari (at least) does not execute JavaScript code that is on a page which is loaded entirely via jQuery's load() method.

However, I think that I figured out how to deal with it!

On the 1776.php page, move the SCRIPT element from the HEAD to the BODY of the document.

```
<body>
    <script> ... the code ... </script>
    <div> ... </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How should I incoporate this inside of the .html()function and/or <img> tag?

Comment: @jon Just replace `this.href` with `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: This is what I did (it doesnt work):

$("#work").html($("<img>").attr("src", $(this).attr("href")));
return false;

Comment: @jon What happens in Safari? Does the web-page get replaced by the image?

Comment: Yeah, it does. This code is actually doing this in all browsers now.

Comment: @jon Do the browsers report an error? It seems that you got an error in the JavaScript code which disables the even handler.

Comment: I ran firebug and looked in my error console, receiving 0 errors...here is a link to the page I'm working on: http://cprandpartners.com/work/1776.php

Comment: @jon You should have supplied that link from the start. It took me 10 seconds to figure it out. `:)`

Comment: Haha, I figured it was something easy. What is it?

Comment: That didn't work :/ It's working in firefox but still broken up in Safari

Comment: @jon It works in my Safari 5. What Safari version are you testing in?

Comment: I'm in safari 5.0.3....tested it on four different computers in safari. No good in any of them :/

Comment: @jonathan Are those Macs? I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: 3 are macs, one is running XP. On each of them, the image i loaded directly by its URL in a new window. In firefox, the images load into the #work div, as they are intended to

Comment: @jonathan Also, check out the newest version of jQuery - 1.4.4

Comment: That actually worked...I am having this issue, which I didn't think would matter, but apparrently does.
1776.php is loaded dynamically through http://cprandpartners.com/work/home.php, and inside of home.php, it still has the issue it was having before. Click design> 1776 Clothing> then try using the script. Any ideas?

Comment: @jonathon How are you inserting 1776.php into home.php?

Comment: function c1776() {
  $('#container').html('<p align="center"></p>');
  $('#container').css({'right' : '900px'});
  $('#container').load("1776.php");
  $("#container").stop().animate({  right:'0px'  },{queue:false, duration:500, easing: 'linear'});
}

Comment: @jonathon Is the issue present if you open 1776.php directly in Safari? (Did we resolve the original issue?)

Comment: Yeah, we did. It only happens once 1776.php is loaded inside of home.php

Comment: @jonathon Did you accidentally revert to the old code? I'm asking because the 1776.php page - http://cprandpartners.com/work/1776.php - contains your original code, and not the code I posted in my UPDATE 2.

Comment: You're right. It did revert in a recent update..but it's back to your code, and still functioning the same (or lack there of)

Comment: @jonathon You got a copy-paste error (I assume): one of the three `)};` at the end has to be moved right after `return false;` It has to look like so: http://jsfiddle.net/gD78L/

Comment: I've removed the resize script for simplicity. It's now just the code we're looking at. Still getting the same result.

Comment: @jonathon It appears that Safari (at least) does not execute the JavaScript code on a page which is loaded into another page via load(). Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file

Comment: @jonathon I am finally able to experience your issue in my Safari. That will make it easier to resolve the issue.

Comment: @jonathon OK, I think I finally figured it out. View UPDATE 3 in my answer.

Comment: I removed everything with the exception of what's in the body tags and included the jquery inside of this area. Worked like a charm. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @jonathon Yes, as long as the SCRIPT element is **not** inside the HEAD element, the JavaScript code will execute.

Comment: @jonathon I've opened a question addressing this behavior in Safari: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787457/javascript-doesnt-execute-in-safari-when-loading-entire-page-via-jquerys-load

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#thumbnails a").click(function() {
      $('#work').empty().append($('<img>', {
           src:   this.href
      }));
      return false;
});
```

Comment: You've got a `)` instead of a `,` after `'<img>'`.

Answer (score 0):

I its getting confused off the `this.href` because while your in the attribute `$("#work")`.

try this:

```
$("#thumbnails a").click(function() {
    var urlHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#work").html($("<img>").attr("src", urlHref));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: No, that's not an issue. The `this` value would have a different value only if it were inside  a nested function expression / declaration. But it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use css property `background:url(...)` instead of `<img>` tag when appending images through javascript in Safari Mobile only. It won't work with `<img>` tags.

Comment: Where does it say it's running on a mobile?

Comment: Could You explain it, please?