# JavaScript doesn't execute in Safari when loading entire page via jQuery's load() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have these two pages:

**page1.html**

http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/jquery-load-issue/page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrap"> </div>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script> $(function() { $('#wrap').load('page2.html'); }); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/jquery-load-issue/page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script> alert('Page 2 HEAD'); </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> PAGE 2 </p>
    <script> alert('Page 2 BODY'); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I am loading the entire page2.html into the #wrap element of page1.html. Notice, that page2.html contains two SCRIPT elements with alert() function calls - one in the HEAD of the page, and the other one in the BODY of the page.

**The issue:**

In Firefox 3.9, IE9 beta, Chrome (latest) and Opera 11, both alerts execute. 
In Safari 5, only the second alert executes.

Is this a Safari bug?

Comment: There unfortunately just isn't consistent behavior between browsers when inserting a document into a document. I don't think you can call it a bug, because you're attempting invalid HTML, so the corrections (if any) are left up to the implementation. Are you willing to consider ugly solutions?

Comment: @patrick Well, the solution to this issue (obviously) is to put all SCRIPT elements inside the BODY of the document (where they belong anyway) `:)`.

Comment: Yes, if you're able to alter the response server-side, then that (or more appropriately sending only the desired content) would be the obvious solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like this is a Safari issue, but maybe not a bug (and may happen in other browsers):

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>, <title>, or <head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

I'm guessing that applies to anytime `.load()` is used, not just when getting fragments. But I think it would be best, since you are pulling content into a `<body>` element that it not include a `<head>` tag?

Comment: Great answer. One should either use an fragment identifier, like: `load('page2.html #content')`, or let page2.html be just a HTML snippet without the HEAD part of the document.

Comment: helped me ur answer in finding solution for my question, thanks ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687981/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-tab-method-not-working-after-ajax-loading-of-some-page/14693495#14693495