# Javascript function does not work after page loaded via Jquery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

But here's the crazy thing, this only happens with Safari. The function works as it should on Chrome, IE< and Firefox.

I tried adding:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var myfunctionhere = function()
      {
      //my function
      }
});
```

Anyone got any ideas what is going on with Safari here and how I can get it to play nice.

Comment: I don't think we can help much, if y<ou don't show us the function.. Or: Have you tried replacing the function with a simple `alert("test");`? Did that not run either?

Comment: Please elaborate. How are you loading a page via Ajax? Is the script tag in which the js function was residing is getting replaced by the new content?

Comment: Are invoking your function? In your example it is just decleared.

Comment: I did try just the alert and that didn't work - but, I didn't see this before I posted:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787457/javascript-doesnt-execute-in-safari-when-loading-entire-page-via-jquerys-load

But the solution was to get rid of everything but the script and the content inside of the body - remove the html, head, and body tags.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to get rid of everything but the script and the content inside of the body - remove the html, head, and body tags.

This was also addressed here [JavaScript doesn't execute in Safari when loading entire page via jQuery's load() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787457/javascript-doesnt-execute-in-safari-when-loading-entire-page-via-jquerys-load)