# Twitter bootstrap tabs "tab" method not working after ajax loading of some page content

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using twitter bootstrap in my work. The "tab" method 
(ie; `$("a element under tab li").tab("show")` ) swiches to the new tab specified by the jQuery selector perfectly, until an ajax loading is done. When I create a new tab using `jQuery append`, load its pane content by `jQuery load` and try to switch to that new tab using tab("show") it gives error element doesnt have a method `tab`

UPDATE

```
    <div class="tabbable">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab-set">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1"> tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="ajax" href="test.html">tab 4 - ajax</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active"> tab 1 content </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane"> tab 2 content </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane"> tab 3 content </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the javascript code to add new tab via ajax

```
$("#tab-set").append("<li id='"+tabType+"'><a href='#" + tabType +
       "-pane' data-toggle=\"tab\"> " + tabName + "</a></li>");

$("#tab-content").append("<div class=\"tab-pane\" id=\"" +tabType + "-pane\"></div>");
$("#" + tabType + "-pane").load(tabUrl);
```

After adding new tab i try to switched to that tab using

```
$("#" + tabType + " a").last().tab("show");
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
$("#tab-content").append("<div class=\"tab-pane\" id=\"" +tabType + "-pane\"></div>");
```

You have #tab-content, but your div actually has a class of tab-content, not an id. So it needs to be:

```
$(".tab-content").append("<div class=\"tab-pane\" id=\"" +tabType + "-pane\"></div>");
```

I tested your code by creating variables for tabType, tabName, and tabUrl, and it works for me with that tiny change I mentioned above. But I wasn't able to get the same error as you (element doesnt have a method tab) so if this still doesn't work for you there's something else going on and you will need to post more of your code.

Comment: sorry , i have id 'tab-content', i missed it in the above sample, i have updated the code

Comment: found the problem & solution myself, anyways thanks for the try, upvoted ur answer, hope u do mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i got the trouble now.

I was loading a page using `$("#" + tabType + "-pane").load(tabUrl);` na, that page also had html, head, body elements and it was also loading jquery in it. That created the problem. Its something related to the problem given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787457/javascript-doesnt-execute-in-safari-when-loading-entire-page-via-jquerys-load)

Now i changed the contents of the loading pages that it loads only the basic inside elements needed, without tags like html, head, script, body etc.

This was giving headache for me a whole day. Thank god that i finally fixed it.

EDIT

Not even need to remove all elements. Just need to take care of not loading jquery again from that loading page (loading via $("#" + tabType + "-pane").load(tabUrl);).

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you fixed it. Upvoted for solution, seems like it could help someone who has the same error message.

Comment: @frostyterrier : thanks for that, nice to meet you, hope i'll get ur help in future too