# Change a buttons id on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to change the `id` attribute of a `div` on click.

```
<div class="xtra" id="id1"><a href="#"><span>Next</span></a></div>
```

How would I do that?

I've tried:

```
$j("#id1").attr('id', 'id2');
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$j("#id1").live('click',function(){
      $(this).attr('id', 'id2'); //use this one
      this.id = 'id2'; //or this one <-- they both do the same thing
})
```

I am not sure why you would ever want to do this, that is how you would do it.

IDs are not meant to change, they are meant to be unique to a specific element.

Classes are usually used when changing css back and forth.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that IDs are not meant to change. Note that a sneaky consequence of using `live()` here is that the handler will no longer be triggered after the ID is changed.

Comment: @Box9, the reason why i placed `live()` there was just in case the OP changes another element to that id

Comment: @Neal Just `this.id = 'id2';`

Comment: @Neal, yup it makes perfect sense. I wasn't suggesting anything else - it's just something to be wary of since `live` doesn't attach the handler to the element itself.

Comment: @Sime yes that too, ill add it to the answer

Comment: @Neal My point is that setting the `id` property directly is better. In general, the `attr()` method is not needed for setting/getting DOM properties (properties on DOM elements defined by the DOM standards). There are a couple of exceptions like `href` and `src`. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456231/retrieving-html-attribute-values-the-dom-0-way